# Karma + Jasmine testing async methods

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following controller:

```
export default function($scope, $state, $http) {
    $scope.login = () => {
        $scope.loginFailed = false;

        const postReq: object = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: `/login`,
            data: {},
        }

        try {
            console.log('$scope.login');

            const response = await $http(postReq);

            console.log('login done');

            console.log('$state.go');

            $state.go('dashboard');

            return true;
        } catch(err) {
            console.error(err);
            $scope.loginFailed = true;

            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

I'm trying to test this method with Jasmine

```
it('change state to dashboard', async (done) => {
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('/login', undefined).respond(201, { rmId: 123123 });

    await $scope.login();
    expect($state.current.name).toBe('dashboard');
});
```

The results of my tests are as follows:

> LOG: '$scope.login'
>   PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) $scope.login change state to dashboard FAILED

Now it seems that Jasmine isn't waiting for the `$http` call to be completed. (This works fine when I manually test it in a browser)

Is there a better way to correctly test async methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to do the await. you just need to flush the backend mock before expect test
your login function must be change like this:

```
$scope.login = () => {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          $scope.loginFailed = false;

        const postReq = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: `/login`,
            data: {},
        }

        const response = $http(postReq).then(
          (success) => {
              $state.go('dashboard');
              resolve(true);
            },
            (error) => {
               $scope.loginFailed = true;

            reject(false);
            });
       });
    };
```

And your test like :

```
it('change state to dashboard', async (done) => {
    const  backendMock = $httpBackend;
    backendMock.expectPOST('/login').respond(201, { rmId: 123123 });
    $scope.login().then((response) => {
      expect($state.current.name).toBe('dashboard');
      done();
    });
    backendMock.flush();

});
```

Comment: So I've added the `flush`, but my logs are the same. It never seems to get passed the `$http` call.

Comment: did you create a variable and set the $httpBackend and not just do $httpBackend.flush();

Comment: i also think that the  await you put on the controller is not a good idea. it would be better to catch the promise in a then() callback and do the stuffs you want when there is a response

Comment: `$scope.login().then(() => console.log('ok')); $httpBackend.flush();` I tried this before, but I feel that my `login()` method is just never fully executed. It never gets past `await $http(postReq);`

Comment: I modified my response try this and let me know the result

Comment: I understand what you're doing, but I really don't want to update a simple method just so that my tests would work. That sounds fairly counter intuitive.

Comment: But you're response is correct, seems Angular doesn't work properly with async / await. I've reverted it back to a simple promise and was able to test that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  `$httpBackend.flush();` before writing your assertions. Add this line before your `expect` statement. It should work..

Comment: I just tried that, but the results are the same. I never see full logging of my `$scope.login` method.